# Pasting data in the last row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste data from sheet(template) to sheet(main) on the last used cell in column A.

But i cant seem to get the result i want.

```
Dim lastrow As Long

If Range("a1").Value = "A" Then        
    Sheets("Template").Range("a1:e9").Copy
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Main").Range("a" & lastrow).paste        
End If
```

**ERROR** : `Sheets("Main").Range("a" & lastrow).paste` (object does not support this property or method)

Comment: What is the result you want and what are you getting? Any errors?

Comment: `Sheets("Main").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to fully qualify all your objects and variables (never assume or rely on `ActiveSheet`).

Also, the `Copy` >> `Paste` is a 1-line command (not 2). If you want to use 2-lines, then change the second one to `PasteSpecial` (even though it's not needed in your case).

```
If Sheets("Template").Range("A1").Value = "A" Then
    lastrow = Sheets("Main").Cells(Sheets("Main").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Template").Range("A1:E9").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Main").Range("A" & lastrow + 1)
End If
```

Comment: I used your code, it doesnt show the error anymore but it is still not pasting anything at the last row

Comment: @Hank is the value in cell "A1" in sheet `"Template"` = `"A"` ?

Comment: You are on fire today :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout i'm only lagging 6 years of knowledge from you (and around 80K), but finaly today is a "good day at work", I can focus on my VBA.

Comment: oops. Sheets("Template").Range("A1:E9").Copy Destinaton:=Sheets("Main").Range("A" & lastrow) << error: application defined or object defined error

Comment: It is pasting now, but the paste keeps cutting off part of the previous one eg. if i paste 6 lines then i run the code again, 2 lines from the previous paste gets cuts off. is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get only values of data then you can use variant.

```
Dim vDB as Variant
Dim rngT As Range
Dim Ws As Worksheet

    vDB = Sheets("Template").Range("a1:e9")
    Set Ws = Sheets("Main")
    With Ws
        If .Range("a1").Value = "A" Then
            Set rngT = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) ' it's lastrow +1
            rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: Set rngT = .Range("a1" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)  << this row is showing errors

Comment: @Hank: mistake   Set rngT = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)